# Return DIV to original height after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 3 DIVs ('event') each with a child DIV ('event-details'). I want to be able to save the height original of 'event-details' (it varies depending on the 'event'), and then set height of 'event-details' to 126px. Then after clicking on a button ('more') I want 'event-details' to return to the original height.

What I have so far saves the 'event-details' heigh, changes it to 126px but after clicking on 'more' it changes the height of 'event-details' to 222px, regardless of the original height it has.

Any help?

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    $('.event').each(function() {
        var eventHeight = $(this).find('.event-details').height();
        console.log( eventHeight );

        $('.more').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).parent('.event').toggleClass('show');
            $('.show > .event-details').css( 'height', eventHeight);
        });

    });

    $('.event-details').css( 'height', '126' );

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="event event-1925">
   <div class="event-details">
      <div class="year">1925</div>
      <div class="title">Home Away</div>
      <div class="copy">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="more">MORE</a>
</div>

<div class="event event-1925">
   <div class="event-details">
      <div class="year">1925</div>
      <div class="title">Home Away</div>
      <div class="copy">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="more">MORE</a>
</div>

<div class="event event-1925">
   <div class="event-details">
      <div class="year">1925</div>
      <div class="title">Home Away</div>
      <div class="copy">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="more">MORE</a>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `eventHeight` is not retained across the click events as the click happens later (and the value was not a parameter to a function to retain it).

Comment: Can you clarify more on this part: "I want to be able to save the height original of 'event-details' (it varies depending on the 'event')"

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that the variable event height will be reset in the first each loop with the height of the next event div, so essentially you will be left with the height of the final div. You need to store the height of each div in an array or object and then retrieve it.

HTML

Use a unique identifier in the html e.g. an id

```
<div class="event event-1925">
  <div id="event-1"  class="event-details">
   .....
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {

  //create array to store all the event div heights
  var eventHeights = [];

  $('.event').each(function() {
    var eventHeight = $(this).find('.event-details').height();
    console.log( eventHeight );

    //get the id of the event div
    var id = $(this).find('.event-details').attr('id');

    //store the height with reference to the div id
    eventHeights[id] = eventHeight;


    $('.more').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent('.event').toggleClass('show');

        //get the id of the event div
        var id = $(this).parent('.event').find('.event-details').attr('id');

        //use id to get the event div's height from array
        $('.show > .event-details').css( 'height', eventHeights[id]);
    });

  });

  $('.event-details').css( 'height', '126' );
```

});

I have not tested this and it could do with being optimised but hopefully it gives you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to build the expandable field set view. Basically in less View you want to show the title or summary and on expand you show more details. The above answer will work fine. Below is another way you can do it with small animations. To see a working example take a look at this [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nlxwL)

your HTML markup for 2 events will be

```
<div class=" event event-1925">
 Event Summary <a class="toogleButton">LESS</a>
</div>     
<div class="event-details">
  <div class="year">1925</div>
  <div class="title">Home Away</div>
  <div class="copy">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>

<div class=" event event-1925">
 Event Summary <a class="toogleButton">LESS</a>
</div>     
<div class="event-details">
  <div class="year">1925</div>
  <div class="title">Home Away</div>
  <div class="copy">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>
```

The script

```
$(".event").click(function () {
    $header = $(this);
    $content = $header.next();
    $toogleBut = $header.children().first()
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        $toogleBut.text(function () {
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "LESS" : "MORE";
        });
    });

});
```

Finally a simple CSS to set initial styles like your required height

```
.event{
  height:126px;
}
```